# Classic ASP. Show new key and value in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, asp-classic

I 'm new to classic asp and got a problem with the dictionary object. What i'm trying to do is when i POST a new key and value. it will dynamically add a new key and value into the dictionary and show it to the browser.

Whenever i POST a new key and value it doesn't save what i've POSTed

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form method="post" action="form.asp">
  <input type="text" id="key" name="key" /> <br />
  <input type="text" id="value"name="value" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>

  <%

 Dim key
 Dim value

  key = request.form("key")
  value = request.form("value")

   Set d = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   d.add key,value

      Response.Write("<p>The value of the keys are:</p>")
              a=d.Keys
          for i = 0 To d.Count -1
             s = s & a(i) & "<br />"
           next
           Response.Write(s)
              %>
          </body> 
       </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to store the Dictionary in Session then take it from there every time, add the item and update the Session:

```
Dim d
If IsObject(Session("d")) Then
    Set d = Session("d")
Else  
    Set d = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End If
d.add key, value
Set Session("d") = d
```

This way every time user will post data, it will be added to the global storage.
Note, by default Session expires after 20 minutes of user being idle.

Comment: Yup, like I said yesterday - dictionary needs to be stored in a session value

Answer (score 1):

Try this to show key and value.
To save it you will need to put the dictionary object into a session value or save the dictionary values as an array.

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="form.asp">
<input type="text" id="key" name="key" /> <br />
<input type="text" id="value"name="value" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<%

Dim key
Dim value

key = request.form("key")
value = request.form("value")

Set d = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.add key,value

Response.Write("<p>The value of the keys are:</p>")
a=d.keys
b=d.items
for i = 0 To d.Count - 1
   s = s & a(i) & "=" & b(i) & "<br />"
next
Response.Write(s)
%>
</body>
</html>
```